# Javascript .toLocaleString() returns wrong month?

Tags: javascript, firefox, internationalization, chromium

I’m at a loss here. I need to display a JavaScript date in my locale, but the displayed locale string is off by 1 month in the future.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var d = new Date(2018,4,3,21,0);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleString('de-DE');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The displayed result is `3.5.2018, 21:00:00` instead of `3.4.2018, 21:00:00`. It works correctly if I try `Date.now()` instead.

Tested on both Ubuntu 14.04.5 and Linux Mint 17.3, with Firefox 59.0.2 (64-Bit) and Chromium 65.0.3325.181.

If I’m not overlooking something, I consider this a **serious bug**, but before filing an issue (where?) I thought I’d ask here.

Thanks for any input on this matter!

Comment: Months are indexed starting at 0, so month 0 is January. In the Date construction, 4 is May.

Comment: Thanks, you’re right. I never expected such inconsistency, like counting days from 1 and months from 0. I’ll now have to convert values I get elsewhere, pluck out the month, convert it to numeric, subtract one and construct dates. Phooey.

But anyway, thanks for pointing this out to me! (You should have made it an answer, I can’t upvote comments …)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Js new Date() starts counting Month from 0 to 11.
When, you are entering new Date(2018,4,3)
It's been calculated as 3-May-2018.
And, the output is 3/5/2018.

Comment: Thanks, I didn’t expect this type of inconsistency (in my eyes), see comment to @Andy G above. Since the question is solved, I’ll accept this answer for now.

Answer (score 2):

The month parameter in the `Date()` constructor is 0-based.

You may find this helpful:

> The argument month is 0-based. This means that January = 0 and December = 11.
>   - [Date - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

display Date in my locale Machin and Next Months

```
 var d = new Date();
 d.setMonth(d.getMonth() +1);
 console.log(d.toLocaleDateString("de-DE", { month: 'long' }));
 return d.toLocaleDateString("de-DE", { month: 'long' })
```